# Best way of saving image file and to save memory

Tags: c#, .net, image, byte, compression

In my program i am creating some big pictures (`Image` objects), and saving them to disk. Then I add them to a list `List<Image>` but after saving 50 pictures and adding them as `Image` objects to my `imageList` it eats up a loooooot of memory. I tried doing this on 50 images and just saving pure image object, my program went up to 160 MB in process manager. So I must find out a way of saving the pictures and adding them to the list without the program eating up all memory.

So I have a couple of solutions and I would love to hear what you think about them or if you have any better ones.

1. Compress the `byte[]` array of the image object.
2. Compress the stream of the memorysteam object.
3. Convert the `byte[]` array of the image object to string and then compress the string.

I am doing this in c#.

Comment: Have you received an `OutOfMemoryException` or are you simply just trying to use the Task Manager to diagnose the performance of the application?

Comment: What do you want to use your Image List for?

Comment: @Bryan Crosby no i havent received an exception but i probably will with 1000 images.

Comment: @dario_ramos i am adding them to a list , so i can later load them from a scroll bar to a picturex. When user scrolls i change the picture.

Comment: Yup, nothing like a bitmap to eat up lots of memory.  It is internally stored in a format that makes it *very* quick to render.  An uncompressed format.  That's why your computer has RAM chips.  Use them or lose them.

Comment: Why don't you simply add the path of the image to your list, instead of the image-object itself. That way you can simply load it and display it when needed, but strings don't take up much memory.

Comment: 160MB is not a lot, especially if you need to be working with 50 images at once. You can imagine each image is probably 3MB, with 50, you can expect 150MB. I think you probably don't need 50 loaded at once and that will solve your issue. Other comments have given suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do not compress your images using the .Net DeflateStream or such (as there is a known issue where it actually increases the size of the data, in all cases) - save it directly to something like a .png.

```
Bitmap bmp;
// ...
bmp.Save("foo.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Make sure you dispose the images that you created (after you have saved them).

You can't compress the images in memory - because Windows GDI (which .Net uses) requires the images in, essentially, uncompressed bitmap form (so when you load a compressed image it will get decompressed).

You should look at loading them on-demand. Here is a class similar to `ImageList` which you may find useful:

```
public class DelayedImagedList : Component
{
    // Item1 = Dispose for the image.
    // Item2 = At creation: the method to load the image. After loading: the method to return the image.
    // Item3 = The original filename.
    private List<Tuple<Action, Func<Image>, string>> _images = new List<Tuple<Action,Func<Image>,string>>();
    private Dictionary<string, int> _imageKeyMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    // Access images.
    public Image this[string key] { get { return _images[_imageKeyMap[key]].Item2(); } }
    public Image this[int index] { get { return _images[index].Item2(); } }
    public int Count { get { return _images.Count; } }

    // Use this to add an image according to its filename.
    public void AddImage(string key, string filename) { _imageKeyMap.Add(key, AddImage(filename)); }
    public int AddImage(string filename)
    {
        var index = _images.Count;
        _images.Add(Tuple.Create<Action, Func<Image>, string>(
            () => {}, // Dispose
            () => // Load image.
            {
                var result = Image.FromFile(filename);
                // Replace the method to load the image with one to simply return it.
                _images[index] = Tuple.Create<Action, Func<Image>, string>(
                    result.Dispose, // We need to dispose it now.
                    () => result, // Just return the image.
                    filename);
                return result;
            }, 
            filename));
        return index;
    }

    // This will unload an image from memory.
    public void Reset(string key) { Reset(_imageKeyMap[key]); }
    public void Reset(int index)
    {
        _images[index].Item1(); // Dispose the old value.
        var filename = _images[index].Item3;

        _images[index] = Tuple.Create<Action, Func<Image>, string>(
            () => { }, 
            () =>
            {
                var result = Image.FromFile(filename);
                _images[index] = Tuple.Create<Action, Func<Image>, string>(
                    result.Dispose, 
                    () => result, 
                    filename);
                return result;
            }, 
            filename);
    }

    // These methods are available on ImageList.
    public void Draw(Graphics g, Point pt, int index) { g.DrawImage(this[index], pt); }
    public void Draw(Graphics g, int x, int y, int index) { g.DrawImage(this[index], x, y); }
    public void Draw(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height, int index) { g.DrawImage(this[index], x, y, width, height); }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            foreach (var val in _images) { val.Item1(); }
            _images.Clear();
            _imageKeyMap.Clear();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: When a compression algorithm increases the size of some files, that's not “an issue”. That's a fact that holds for all imaginable compression algorithms. You can't have an algorithm that can compress anything, that's not mathematically possible.

Comment: @svick. I know know about information theory and entropy. There is a bug. I don't have the connect.microsoft.com link handy, but it's been reported and acknowledged. It very rarely drops the size.

Comment: Okay, if `DeflateStream` really had that bug, that's not a reason not to use general compression methods (like `GZipStream`). But you seem to imply that.

Comment: @svick - `GZipStream` wraps `DeflateStream` by the way :). It's a pretty nasty bug.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Where can I learn more about that bug?

Comment: @svick - I think [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93636/gzipstream-deflatestream-increase-file-size-on-compression) is the one (there are a bunch on connect though). The tree is hardcoded for english text, fancy that!

Answer (score 3):

why compress? Surely you don't have to show all images at the same time (not in full resolution) - so either create smaller thumbs or show only a small subset.

Comment: Well even thought i aint showing the pictures, i am still saving them and its the saving part i am asking about.

Comment: but after saving to disk you can discard the images from memory and reload if needed can't you?

Comment: I cant do that , because i need to have it all in my memory. I am showing the pictures 1 and 1 in a picturebox with a scrollbar that can change the pictures. I tried to load it from the disk every time i scrolled but it was to laggy and when i tried loading from memory it went really fast. Thats why i want them in memory also.

Comment: well it I think compressing/decompressing will even be slower - either you have speed or memory ;) - maybe if you preload a couple (3-4)?

Comment: yes i can do that also but if i manage to save them in memory compressed , then my problem will be solved. And there is pretty fast compress techniques, i just got to find the right one for me.

Comment: I still think a reasonable precached collection will be far more performat - you are talking about 1000 images! But if you want some compression: I don't think you can get much better than saving as JPG in a reasonable time

Comment: Is this scrolling always going to be 1 -> 2 / 2 -> 1 linear? or will there be 'jumping'

you could always 'preload' just a handful of images as you are approaching them. not perfect, but lets face it.. I've seen it done though.

Answer (score 2):

since the images are changed by a scroll bar, why not show only the subset of images around the current index, like if you have 10 images and you are at #5, only load 4/5/6 and unload the rest, and as the scroll moves to 6 load 7, if you have lots of images and you are afraid the scroll movement will be faster than loading, you can load 3/4/5/6/7 and when it moves to 6 load 8, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When using WPF you can simply save the images in a list of MemoryStreams which contain the images as PNG or JPEG. Then you can bind to the images using some converter or a wrapper class that creates an ImageSource object with a reduced resolution. Unfortunately you didn't tell which technique you are using and I currently don't know a solution for WinForms.

```
public List<MemoryStream> ImageStreams {get; private set;}

public static ImageSource StreamToImageSource(Stream stream)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 200;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    bitmapImage.Freeze();

    return bitmapImage;
}
```

When doing this you'll only store some kB per image and the loaded image for the UI will be scaled down, so that the used memory is limited.

With this approach I could load over 100 images in a scanner application and they were all displayed in a `ListBox` with a `VirtualizingStackPanel` side by side with a vertical resolution of 800 pixels. The original images had a resolution of over 2200 x 3800 pixels and 24 bpp.

Loading a PNG with several million pixels normaly takes a second, but with this solution you won't need to load them from disk.

And don't forget to dispose and remove temporary objects etc. You can also run `GC.Collect()` to make sure that unused data will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I like the 2nd choice. Saving your Image to memory using PNG format should be more efficient than using a common compress library like zlib or gzipstream.

```
MemoryStream mStream= new MemoryStream ();
myBitmap.Save( mStream, ImageFormat.Png );
// and then do myBitmap.Dispose() to retrieve the memory?
```